# How to filter a column after being reordered to another position using jQuery DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and applying [Individual column searching (select inputs)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). So on table footer, there is a select on each column to filter data.

I implemented [ColReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/) extension which gives you the ability to reorder columns in a DataTable through a click and drag operation.

It works fine but when I drag a column let's say '**Office**' in my example and drop it as the first column then I select an option for example '**London**' I get 'no matching result'.

The reason is: the search is still using the initial column index before reordering. So it's basically searching 'London' in column 'Name' as it was the first column before reordering.

I found some threads on how to apply column filtering with column reordering as [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/examples/initialisation/col_filter.html) but couldn't make it work.

I used `column.index( 'visible' ).search( val ? val : '', true, false ).draw();`

Also

```
var column = this;
var columnIndex = column.index();
table.column( columnIndex+':visible' ).search( val ? val : '', true, false ).draw();
```

But none leads to a result. Any suggestions please what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

  "colReorder": { realtime: false },

initComplete: function () {

this.api().columns().every( function () {
//for each column I add bootstrap selectpicker to the footer
var column = this;
var select = $('<select class="form-control show-tick dropup" data-dropup-auto="false" data-container="body" data-header="Select option(s)" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" title="All" data-selected-text-format="count > 0" multiple><option value=""></option></select>')
.appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
.on( 'change', function () { 
//everytime the options change I join the selected options as my select is multiple and search those values in that column and draw my DataTable
var data =  $(this).val() ;
if (data.length === 0) { data = [""]; }
var val = data.join('|');
console.log(val);
column.search( val ? val : '', true, false ).draw(); } );
//Here I get unique values of current column and append them as options inside my select
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' ) } );
//apply bootstrap selectpicker on my select
$("select").selectpicker({ dropupAuto: false });
} );
}
} );

  
        
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`column-reorder`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/column-reorder) event to track changes to column ordering.

This requires a bit of logic, because each column re-order is only tracked in terns of how it differs from the *previous* order - and here we need to track how it changes in comparison to the *original* column order.

Here is an event function to handle that:

```
  // This section tracks the location of each column as it is
  // reordered. the colIndexes array holds the original column
  // index values in the order in which they are now displayed:
  var colCount = 6;
  // start a with [0...n] array, where n is the number of columns:
  var colIndexes = [...Array(colCount).keys()]; 
  // see https://datatables.net/reference/event/column-reorder
  table.on( 'column-reorder', function ( e, settings, details ) {
    var curr = details.mapping;
    var temp =  new Array(colCount);
    for ( var i = 0; i < curr.length ; i++ ) {
      // This uses the change event to determine the impact on the
      // original column ordering. 
      temp[curr[i]] = colIndexes[i];
    }
    colIndexes = temp;
    console.log("idx  : " + colIndexes);
  } );
```

Now, in your existing `initComplete` function we can make use of this. First I need access to the API from within the column loop:

```
var dtApi = this.api();
```

Then I use this inside the column loop as follows:

```
var currentColIdx = colIndexes[column.index()];
var dataColumn = dtApi.columns(currentColIdx);
```

This ensures we get the correct column data regardless of how the columns have been reordered.

Finally, when performing the search, we use this column data:

```
dataColumn.search( val ? val : '', true, false ).draw(); } );
```

Here is the full script for testing. And I used it with the HTML data from the question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

    //colReorder: true,
    "colReorder": { realtime: false },

    initComplete: function () {

      var dtApi = this.api();

      this.api().columns().every( function () {
        //for each column I add bootstrap selectpicker to the footer
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select class="form-control show-tick dropup" data-dropup-auto="false" data-container="body" data-header="Select option(s)" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" title="All" data-selected-text-format="count > 0" multiple><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () { 
        //everytime the options change I join the selected options as my select is multiple and search those values in that column and draw my DataTable
        var data =  $(this).val() ;
        if (data.length === 0) { data = [""]; }
        var val = data.join('|');

        var currentColIdx = colIndexes[column.index()];
        //console.log(val);
        //console.log(column.data());
        
        var colValues = dtApi.columns(currentColIdx).data()[0];
        var dataColumn = dtApi.columns(currentColIdx);
        console.log(dataColumn);
        console.log(colValues);

        dataColumn.search( val ? val : '', true, false ).draw(); } );
        //Here I get unique values of current column and append them as options inside my select
        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' ) } );
        //apply bootstrap selectpicker on my select
        $("select").selectpicker({ dropupAuto: false });
      } );

    }

  } );

  // This section tracks the location of each column as it is
  // reordered. the colIndexes array holds the original column
  // index values in the order in which they are now displayed:
  var colCount = 6;
  // start a with [0...n] array, where n is the number of columns:
  var colIndexes = [...Array(colCount).keys()]; 
  // see https://datatables.net/reference/event/column-reorder
  table.on( 'column-reorder', function ( e, settings, details ) {
    var curr = details.mapping;
    var temp =  new Array(colCount);
    for ( var i = 0; i < curr.length ; i++ ) {
      // This uses the change event to determine the impact on the
      // original column ordering. 
      temp[curr[i]] = colIndexes[i];
    }
    colIndexes = temp;
    console.log("idx  : " + colIndexes);
  } );
        
} );   

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. exactly what i needed